# After formatting my PC bitlocker won't ask for a password to access external partition

Tags: windows-7, encryption, bitlocker

I used Bitlocker to encrypt one partition of my removable hard drive.

I definitely remember my password but I don't have the recovery key. I had to format my computer and now when I try to open the partition it won't ask for my password but only give me the option to find the recovery key on the computer or type the infinite-long key manually.

Is there any way to unlock the partition with my password only?

I'm using Windows 7 (64-bit).

Comment: This is to be expected per how Bitlocker works

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you've lost your data.

Bitlocker absolutely requires the recovery key to unlock the drive.  It was not your password that was securing the drive; it was the recovery key the whole time.  Your password was simply unlocking the recovery key which was then used to unlock the drive.  You destroyed that key when you reformatted the OS drive.

I hope you have a backup.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure? I have some VHDs that decrypt fine after doing a clean install of Windows.